# Paths /ASP.NET/Https and /Microsoft/UserSecrets) not shared on OS X

Tags: macos, docker, asp.net-core

I'm getting this error, I know that Docker on MacOS have some problem sharing content, but I dont know how to share this folder in Docker Preferences, I cant find this Folders, The user secret is inside the `/User` and should already be shared.

```
WARNING: The DOCKER_REGISTRY variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The APPDATA variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Starting indoortracker_indoortracker.api_1 ... error

ERROR: for indoortracker_indoortracker.api_1  Cannot start service indoortracker.api: b'Mounts denied: 
    The paths /ASP.NET/Https and /Microsoft/UserSecrets\r\nare not shared from OS X and are not known to Docker.
    You can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.
    See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more info.

ERROR: for indoortracker.api  Cannot start service indoortracker.api: b'Mounts denied: 
    The paths /ASP.NET/Https and /Microsoft/UserSecrets\r\nare not shared from OS X and are not known to Docker.
    You can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.
    See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more info.

ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Comment: Please provide us your docker-compose file